# How to refer to sections of an S-shaped curve?

Tags: terminology

Suppose that I have an S-shaped curve. What term do I use to refer to each of these three separate sections of the curve:

1. the upper section, which starts from the top end to the leftmost bend,
2. the middle section, which starts from the leftmost bend to the rightmost bend, and
3. the lower section, which starts from the rightmost bend to the bottom end?

Are upper tail and lower tail acceptable to refer to 1 and 3? What to call 2?

Comment: Upper, middle and lower sections may suffice, though it depends on proportion and scale, etc.

Comment: I think for most purposes there are only *two* "sections" in an S-curve (separated by an [***inflection point***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)).

Answer (score 2):

In typography, for the letter S, the middle section is referred to as the **spine** of the letter; the upper and lower parts don't have a specific term as far as I know (beyond ‘curved stroke’) but you could maybe use **“shoulders”**, generally used for the arch in the letters m, n, h.

Using the anatomy of typography for a shape that's not meant to be a letter is up to you, but this could be a good starting point. I don't think “tail” is a good word for the upper and lower parts, but upper/middle/lower “sections” could be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As a S-curve, or sigmoid function, all derivative points are positive, so you can not use an offhand specific universally point for all curves of that type.

However, with the normalization of the function, as you see in the following image, one can use a definite slope for references to the upper and lower part of the curve, for instance, those points ahead and before +/- 1.0 radian, respectively.

[image: Examples of sigmoid function, source: Wikipedia]
Perhaps this definition is too mathematical to your message context. I would use only if needed to be very specific and let no somber of doubt to the reader.

Comment: I am referring to a curve that really looks like an S, not a sigmoid where all derivatives are positive.

Comment: I was thinking about a sigmoid. In your case, you can define the points where the tangent is 90 degrees, or the vertical ones, as divisors of upper, middle and lower part.

Comment: @adipro 'S-shaped' curve usually means sigmoid. If you're not thinking of sigmoid, can you elaborate your description of the curve or, even better, draw it?